# Android: How to implement callback on async task which fetch Google token?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-signin

I'm trying to implement google sign in on my app. I manage to sign in and store the token, but as the task is asynchronous I don't know when it finishes so I cannot use the token safely in further methods. How could I add a callback method to `onPostExecute` ?

Here is the code:

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    // onConnected indicates that an account was selected on the device, that the selected
    // account has granted any requested permissions to our app and that we were able to
    // establish a service connection to Google Play services.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected:" + bundle);
    mShouldResolve = false;

    mAccountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

    //HERE I RETRIEVE THE TOKEN AND NEED TO IMPLEMENT CALLBACK
    new RetrieveTokenTask().execute(mAccountName);


    // Show the signed-in UI
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
        onSignInClicked();
    }
}

private void onSignInClicked() {
    // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
    // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
    mShouldResolve = true;
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    // Show a message to the user that we are signing in.
    //mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signing_in);
    Log.i("GoogleSignIn", "in progress");
}


private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String accountName = params[0];
        String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            //startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
        super.onPostExecute(token);
        Log.i("Token Value: ", token);
        //TODO : access token verifier https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth
        accessToken = token;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can start the main activity in the onPostExecute method .. 
That way u will be sure that the task has executed and is about to finish.

Check this

```
private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

 private Callback callback;

public RetrieveTokenTask(Callback callback){
     this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String accountName = params[0];
    String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";
    String token = null;
    try {
        token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
        //startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
    } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return token;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
    super.onPostExecute(token);
    Log.i("Token Value: ", token);
    //TODO : access token verifier https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth
    accessToken = token;
    callback.done();
}
```

}

```
//create an interface
public interface Callback{
  //create the callback method
   void done();
}
```

When starting the task, pass the instance of the callback interface in the constructor like this e.g.

```
new RetrieveTokenTask(this).execute(mAccountName);
```

and Make your activity implement callback interface.
e.g. `MainActivity implements Callback`

Now the MainActivity will have a done method, this method is ur callback.

I hope this explanation was helpful.

Comment: Sure I could do that, but my question was if it was possible to add a callback method to an async task ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use AsyncTask on Android. It is bad, really bad. You will start having memory leaks and that is nasty.

Here's more information why AsyncTask is bad on Android: http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/

For your network calls, why trying to reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of well established and tested libraries that do all the hard work for you, they even provide you with callbacks.

I recommend you [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) from Square, they provide you sync calls as wells as async (callbacks) and observables. Just pick the one you want, most likely the async with callbacks.

Comment: I'm using this as it is what I have found in several places to retrieve the token in google sign in (including the official google doc https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) , once everything works I'll try to implement your suggestions :)